# Is there an R function how to minimize the Tracking Error by finding optimal weights of portfolio assets

Tags: r, solver, portfolio, r-portfolioanalytics

Let´s say I have a portfolio of in total n assets and their returns over x periods and als the return of a benchmark over the same periods. My objective is to find a vector of weights w such that

w∗=arg min TE(w)

where TE(w) is the tracking error defined as follows:

```
 TE = (sum((return.portfolio-return.benchmark)^2)/(x - 1))^0.5
```

In short, I want to replicate the return of a benchmark using a portfolio of n assets over x periods. The only constraints should be that the sum of all assets is equal to one and that no asset has a weight higher than 0.4.

Does anyone have an idea how I could solve this problem with R?

Comment: You can solve such models (at least with standard definitions of TE) via quadratic programming, e.g. with package `quadprog`. Your formula for TE computes the absolute return differences (you square and take the root first; then you take the mean). Is that on purpose or a typo?

Comment: Your´re absolutly right, was a typo, sorry. Using solve.QP with quadprog, how would you chose the dmat matrix in this case? Could I take all returns and then subtrect the returns of the benchmark, square the results, take the root and then divide by (x-1)? Out of this matrix I could provide the covariance matrix, which is dmat.

Comment: I have some notes here http://enricoschumann.net/notes/return-based-tracking-portfolios.html The `NMOF` package has, in its development version, a function `trackingPortfolio`, which implements this problem as a QP: https://github.com/enricoschumann/NMOF/blob/master/R/portfolio.R#L331:L391

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options. Here is one with `constrOptim` from `stats`:

```
#some data
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

getReturns <- function(symbols, from='2000-01-01') {
  returns <- list()
  for (symbol in symbols) { #symbol=symbols[2]
    sym = getSymbols(symbol, from = from, adjustOHLC = TRUE, auto.assign = FALSE)
    return <- Return.calculate(Ad(sym))
    colnames(return) <- gsub("\\.Adjusted", "", colnames(return))
    returns[[symbol]] <- return
  }
  returns <- do.call(cbind, returns)
  return(returns)
}

symbols <-  c("MSFT","AAPL","AMZN","CSCO","ADBE")
ret <- getReturns(symbols,from="2020-01-01")[-1,]

x = nrow(ret) # periods
N = ncol(ret) # assets

set.seed(1324)
Bench = rnorm(x,0.0015,0.03) #some benchmark
plot(ts(Bench))

# const opt
## needs a feasible starting value
#  A'b >= b0  x < 0.4 --> -x >= -.4 x> -0.4 or 0 if not short selling
# 
fTE <- function(b,rets,Ben) {
  Pret=apply(rets,1,function(rl)sum(rl*b))
  sd(Pret-Ben)
}
upblim=0.4
loblim=-0.4
Amat <- matrix(1, 1, N)
Amat <- rbind(Amat,-diag(N)) # upper limit
Amat <- rbind(Amat,diag(N)) # if lower limit
bvec       <- c(.9999999,rep(-upblim,N),rep(loblim,N))

# feasable sol
ws=c(3,4,5,6,1)
(ws=ws/sum(ws))
Amat %*% ws >= bvec

(sol <- constrOptim(ws, fTE, NULL, ui = Amat, ci = bvec,rets=ret,Ben=Bench))
sum(sol$par)
pie(abs(sol$par),labels = colnames(ret))

#> data.frame(Assets=colnames(ret),ws=sol$par)
#  Assets          ws
#1  MSFT -0.13233070
#2  AAPL  0.39999989
#3  AMZN  0.39999997
#4  CSCO  0.26382163
#5  ADBE  0.06850912
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, which already did some good help! I just have two more doubts: 1. How did you chose the values of ws to minimize tracking error?       2.  If I want to avoid short selling and set loblim to 0.05 it says, that it´s not inside the feasible region. How can I change that?

Comment: About 1. try an error. 2. I tryed with `loblim = 0.05` and found a solution   `Assets         ws
1  MSFT 0.05000014
2  AAPL 0.30387085
3  AMZN 0.39999995
4  CSCO 0.18632966
5  ADBE 0.05979933`